# Is avoiding SQL statements in programs a good idea?

Tags: sql

I recently came across a program which is developed using sql statements in a table with a code for each statement. rather than having specific sql statements in the program itself.

So, rather than having code like this:

```
string query = "SELECT id, name from [Users]";
cmd.ExecuteQuery(query);
```

They use code like this: (simplified)

```
string firstQuery = "SELECT queryText from [Queries] where queryCode = 'SELECT_ALL_USERS'";
string userQuery = cmd.ExecuteQuery(firstQuery);//pretend this directly returns the result of the first query

cmd.ExecuteQuery(userQuery);
```

The logic behind this as far as I've heard is that it makes the program easier to maintain as the developer is free to change the "user sql" without having to actually change the program.

However, this struck me as maybe a little counterproductive. Would this kind of code be considered a good idea?

EDIT: I'm not looking for suggestions like "use an ORM". Assume that sql queries are the only option.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ IMO

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO - the SQL query in question is actually stored in a table; the first query retrieves the query, and the second query executes it.  Yuck.  Sure hope the queries don't need parameters...

Comment: I would use stored procedures instead and call them. But ive seen setups like that before and if its well structured its a good enough approach i would say

Comment: This can't be presented as "Avoiding SQL Queries". "Doubling SQL Queries" might be a better term

Comment: I assume that the second "dynamic" apporach is slow and open for sql-injection. At least open for very nasty errors.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Yes, that's exactly it. And this is only used for queries that don't need parameters...I think.

Comment: I don't find this way of working a good idea, for many reasons :readability, breaking the deploy process, breaking the code 'lifecycle' (the exact same code could have very different result as the queries are in the DB, not in the code), ...

Comment: Also if you have a database problem, not only the query fails, but also the query for the query - making it hard to spot the error.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Ahh I get it .. yeah that's horrible.

Comment: I sure hope inserts, updates, deletes and any queries that need parameters aren't handled this way as well -- or do they use proper bind variables? I'd rather use views or stored procedures.

Comment: Heck, just put the queries in a properties or xml file, if you want to do this. That has a similar advantage of not firing off a major recompile, which is my best guess as to why they don't want to touch the Java code. Places that say "Don't use an ARM" and then roll their own in some weird way are to be avoided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion, this approach is ridiculous.  There is value (maintainability, modularity) in separating as much SQL from the middle tier as possible, but to accomplish this end, I would recommend using stored procedures.

Answer (score 3):

No i really dont think its a good idea to proceed further with design.

As a test or learning activity is a differetn part, but going foward with such implementations is definately not advisable.

**pros:**

*1. We get complete modularity. The Real Business Schema can change at any time, and we do not need to modify the Running application to get the results from Different schema (Considering result Format dont change).*

**Cons.** 
*1.  With this implementation we are firing 2 SQLs to Database each time when we want to execute 1. I/O call including DB calls are always performnace hit, and with this implementation we are doubling the performance  which is definately not advisable.*

Comment: 1 can be achieved even more easily with views or stored procedures.